# Page still get my IP although using Tor and Privoxy

Tags: python, web-scraping, tor, privoxy

I configured Tor browser and privoxy using https://jarroba.com/anonymous-scraping-by-tor-network/. When I checked my IP with http://icanhazip.com/, my IP addresses are changed; it works. But, when I tried to scrape desired website, I got:

> You are attempting to access "website" using an anonymous private/proxy network. Please disable that and try accessing the site again.

Comment: Also, StackOverflow can still tell you're massively off topic thorugh Tor and Privoxy!

Answer (score 4):

Tor hides your IP address, but it does not hide the fact that you are using Tor, since Tor exit relays are public knowledge.  For example, [**xmyip.com**](https://www.xmyip.com/tor-ip-check) will tell you whether or not your IP is a Tor IP.

Given the error you received, it looks like that website blocks Tor users, which is a fairly common practice.  See [**Tor users being actively blocked on some websites**](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/02/29/tor-users-being-actively-blocked-on-some-websites/) for more details.